# How to turn on Break on All Exceptions in Visual Web Developer Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

In Visual Web Developer Express, how do I turn on Break on All Exceptions? I'm looking for the Debug > Exceptions menu item but not finding it, not even if I try to customize the menu.

This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw.aspx) on MSDN suggests that it ought to be possible.

Comment: I don't have this version, but have you tried pressing ctrl+alt+e ?

Comment: Or Ctrl+D,E. Depending on your keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Maybe the information on MSDN is wrong? What options do you have in your Debug menu ?

Comment: Take a look at the Community Content at the bottom of the MSDN article. Other people have the same problem (one person seems to indicate its an issue with VWD)

Answer (score 9):

The exceptions menu isn't shown in Visual Web Developer Express - it's only shown in Visual C# Express (and I assume Visual Basic Express).

However, all hope isn't lost - the default behavior in VWD Express is to break on all exceptions.  If you feel like you're missing an exception, you can try to turn off "Just My Code" debugging, which will catch exceptions thrown in CLR code and linked libraries.

To do this, open up Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General, and uncheck "Just My Code". If you want to step through CLR code, you can also enable that feature on the same screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw.aspx) you quote in your question, did you see the part that says ...

> **Note**
>
> To enable the Exceptions menu in
>   Express versions, on the Tools menu,
>   click Settings, and then select Expert
>   Settings.

Comment: Doesn't work. And the other tip about going into `Customize...` doesn't work either - the menu item just isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You could fudge it by breaking on `std::exception::exception()`, although this is C++ only and it's possible (although inadvisable) that something throws an exception which does not derive from `std::exception`